# How do I only accept internal redirects and ignore all other requests?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress deployment and I want to ignore all external accesses to resources that exists (i.e. files and directories) but I want to accept all internal redirects. The idea is to not reveal to external users that `/wp*` exists. I know that I will have to rename wp-content for this to work (as well as tweak some things in `wp-config.php`, but the bottom line is:

**How do I configure my .htaccess file to only accept internal redirects and to ignore all other requests?**

I think there's `%{ENV_VAR}` somewhere that would let me create a RewriteCond but I couldn't find it in the apache docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "internal accesses" exactly? Can you make an example?

Comment: @Pekka: An "internal redirect" is one that does not force a 30X redirect in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both IVA and hakre's suggested methods. They didn't work for what I was trying to do. The way that I got this to work was similar to what hakre suggested but instead of defining my own variable I use one that is already defined: `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}`. Do something similar to this:

```
  # If the resource requested is a `wp*` file or directory AND it's NOT from a redirect 
  # (notice that the 'match' is an empty string, poop to a 403.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} wp-.*$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the external access the first rule, and make it fail. Then do the internal redirects after.

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?.* - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*) foo/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Won't give wordpress standard 404 page for the failed requests, and does `R=404` actually works, I wondered a bit because it's not documented.

Comment: "Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a redirect (3xx) status code.

If a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used." http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Answer (score 0):

[mod_rewrite supports environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). The notation is `%{ENV:variable}` for RewriteCond and you can set them in RewriteRule with the `env|E=VAR:VAL'` flag. Done it, works.

To return a plain 404 to "hide" away things you must implement your own handling inside wordpress. E.g. send those to be 404 / File Not Found masked requests into worpdress to make it return the 404 error page.

However you must know what you do. E.g. some plugins won't work with the setup you aim to achieve as the precondition is that the client must be able to send requests into locations in `/wp-content` and `/wp-admin`.

Next to that you won't be able to hide that your site is running with wordpress. Javascript files for examples need to be available. You would need to map those onto new URLs both in .htaccess as well as filtering the output to do the actual mapping of the files.

Even if you do so (e.g. by rewriting URLs via an output buffer), you would come up with a sheme that does make visible you're using wordpress.